# Basic Question about Principal Congruence Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms

I'm using Diamond and Shurman's text on Modular Forms and the section on congruence groups states that there is a natural homomorphism from $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ given by reducing entrywise modulo $N$. My question is why is the image of this map necessarily in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$? For example, for $N = 4$, if we took $\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4\\
2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and reduced, we would get $\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\
2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}$ which has determinant 9. Perhaps I'm confused on the definition of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$. Do we reduce the determinant modulo 4 as well?

Comment: Yes, indeed, how do we define $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$, or $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I thought it meant all 2x2 matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ that also had determinant 1, is this correct?

Comment: No, the determinant is an element of the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/N$, so that the determinant is $1$ modulo $N$.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you for your help